# How does Minimax algorithm really work?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm working on Minimax algorithm to build a gomoku game. My problem with Minimax is that with the same evaluation value in child nodes, which is really added to parent node or it is randomly added.
[Example tree from Wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkhUW.png)

So as you can see from the tree above, at ply 3 of Min node, there are 2 child nodes have the value of 6. What node is really added to parent node ?

**Updated question**

Why at the leaves, they are separated to group of 2 or group of 3 which are corresponding to different parent nodes ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What node is really added to parent node ?

In a word, "neither".

You evaluate the nodes, and take the maximum *value*. You add values, not nodes, so if  the best value is shared by multiple nodes there's no need for you to pick between the nodes - you'd get the same result either way. You just take that best value.

Comment: I have one more question. Why at the leaves, they are separated to group of 2 or group of 3 ?

Comment: Each node corresponds to a state (i.e. of the game, or whatever else the algorithm is applied to). The root node is the current state, and at each level the new nodes correspond to a state which can be reached from that node's parent. So ending with 2 (or 3) leaves corresponds to 2 (or 3) legal moves being available from that parent node.

Answer (score 0):

Well, presumably you implemented the algorithm, so you can tell. And since you didn't post your code, we can't.

In general, if your evaluation function can't differentiate between moves, then there's no big problem with choosing either move at random. In fact, there are many games where this is a common event. Symmetry tends to produce situations in which two moves are equally good. And it's clear that in such situations it doesn't matter which move you choose.

As for trees, note that many trees do not order their children, and the MinMax tree is no exception. There's not such a thing as "first child" and "second child".